# Safari некорректно обрабатывает минимизированный css

Tags: css, safari

Добрый день.

Обнаружилось странное поведение Safari при использовании минимизированного css (без минимализации всё прекрасно работает).

Вот участок css, с которым возникла проблема:

```
.input, .input-wrapper, .custom-combobox {
    width: 100% !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    max-width: none !important;
    max-width: none !important
}
```

Вот [ссылка](https://lk.moesk.ru/users/sign_up) на страницу, на которой возникает проблема.

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: Прикладываю ссылки на изображения, демонстрирующие различия в отображении в Chrome и Safari.
http://i.imgur.com/HEocaUf.png  

http://i.imgur.com/qJkIKpj.png

Comment: Нашли решение ?

Comment: Нет, решение пока не найдено

Answer (score 1):

Пропустите все css файлы через [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) и проблема с кроссбраузерностью будет решена

В результате должно получиться

```
.input, .input-wrapper, .custom-combobox {
    width: 100% !important;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box; /*Firefox 1-3*/
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari */
    display: block;
    max-width: none !important;
    max-width: none !important
}
```

Comment: Пропустили пару файлов через autoprefixer, но проблемы остались(